# pipe sox play command to stdout

Tags: linux, audio, stream, pipe, sox

So I'm currently trying to stream my microphone input from my raspberry pi (rasbian)
to some sort of network stream in order to receive it later on my phone.
In order to do this I use `arecord -D plughw:1,0 -f dat -r 44100 |` top pipe the soundstream from my usb-microphone to stdout  which works fine as far as I can see but I needed it to be a bit louder so I can understand people standing far away from it .

So i piped it to the sox play command like this :

`arecord -D plughw:1,0 -f dat -r 44100| play -t raw -b 16 -e signed -c 2 -v 7 -r 44100 - test.wav`
(test.wav is just some random wav file id doesn't work without it and there is a whitespace between the - behind  44100 and test.wav because i think - is a seperate parameter:

`SPECIAL FILENAMES (infile, outfile):
-                        Pipe/redirect input/output (stdin/stdout); may need -t
-d, --default-device     Use the default audio device (where available)`)

I figured out by using the -v parameter i can increase the volume.
This plays the recorded stream to the speakers I connected to the raspberry pi 3 .

**Final goal :** pipe the volume increased soundstream to the stdout(or some fifopipe file) so i can get it from stdin inside  another script to send it to my phone.

However im very confused by the manpage of the play command http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html

i need to select the outputdevice to pipe or stout or something
if you know a better way to just increase the voulme of the i think `Recording WAVE 'stdin' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo`soundstream let me know

Comment: maby this belongs on dsp.stackexchange.com ill post it there if nobody can help me here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I'm aware you can't pipe the output from `play`, you'll have to use the regular `sox` command for that.
For example:

```bash
# example sound file
sox -n -r 48k -b 16 test16.wav synth 2 sine 200 gain -9 fade t 0 0 0.1

# redundant piping
sox test16.wav -t wav - | sox -t wav - gain 8 -t wav - | play -
```

In the case of the command in your question it should be sufficient to change `play` to `sox` and add `-t wav` to let sox know in what format you want to pipe the sound.

```
arecord -D plughw:1,0 -f dat -r 44100 | \
sox -t raw -b 16 -e signed -c 2 -v 7 -r 44100 - -t wav -
```